# Pentaho Kettle Spoon Date manipulation

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am using Pentaho Spoon to do some transformation. I am using 'Table Input' and joining multiple tables to get final output table.

I need to achieve:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct ID)
FROM TBLA join TBLB ON TBLA.ID=TBLB.ID
WHERE
  TBLA.ID=334
  AND TBLA.date = '2013-1-9'
  AND TBLB.date BETWEEN '2012-11-15' AND '2013-1-9';
```

I am manually inserting '2012-11-15' but I am using `Get System Data` to insert '2012-1-9'. I am using 1 `Get System Data`.

My query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct ID)
FROM TBLA join TBLB ON TBLA.ID=TBLB.ID
WHERE
  TBLA.ID=334
  AND TBLA.date='?'
  AND TBLB.date BETWEEN '2012-11-15' AND '?';
```

I get error message in Table Input saying `No value specified for parameter 2`

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple one this; You need to "duplicate" the system date.  So add another line in "get system data" called "date2" or something, make it the same as the first line, and then it will fill in the 2nd parameter or ?

OR simply change the query to say between '2012-11-15' and TBLA.date
then you dont need the 2nd parameter

Comment: Thank you for the response. On the 'get system data' step all I see is the fixed date options such as yesterday date, today date etc. How do I enter my own manual date such as '2012-12-3' or '2012-12-4' etc as an input date to the query?

Comment: Just use the "Add constants" step.

Comment: I removed the 'Get system info' step and directly fed tables with 'Add Constant' step. So basically my table is getting input from 
only 'Add Constant' step with Name as 'Date1' Type as 'Date' Format as 'yyyy-MM-dd' and value as '2013-01-01'. 

2013-01-01 is supposed to replace the query dates 'select ID from TableA where date= ?;


But when I run the transform, I see nothing in my output. Any suggestion?

Also one of my query is like 'select ID from TableA where date between ? and ?' Any suggestion for that as well?

Thank you very much.

Comment: there has to be as many rows coming into the step, as ?'s in the query. you also have to tick the "use data from previous step" option and select the relevant step.  if all else fails then preview the data from the step to be sure it's coming in right.

Comment: Now I understand about having multiple inputs for multiple '?' values.

I am still stuck in giving the constant input to the query. 

I am using 'Add Constants' step to give Name (NewDate), Type (Date), Format (yyyy-MM-dd) and value 2013-01-02. Then I am passing it to 'get system info' step with type being 'previous job entry result'. But still I do not see any output. Any suggestion? :)

Comment: Ah ok; Another quirk of PDI. Some steps e.g. get system info will cause a row of data to start. but add constants will not.  So you need to feed in a row into the add constants step first, perhaps using a generate rows step which just generates 1 row.

Comment: I fed generate rows to tables directly and it works! Thanks @ codek!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer the pattern of a Get System Info/Add Constants step to create one row with multiple columns that feeds into a Database Join step. Then you replace parameters in your query with columns instead of rows, and you can specify a column more than once.